# ajax - по нажатию на кнопку изменить значение переменной php

Tags: php, ajax

Имеется php переменная $page = '';

Пытаюсь после нажатия на кнопку

`<button type="button" class="btn" data-link="?p=1">1</button>`

изменить переменную $page на содержимое data-link

```
    <script>
$('button').click(function(){ //при клике
    $.ajax({ //отправляем ajax-запрос
        type: "POST", //тип (POST, GET, PUT, etc)
        url: "action.php", //УРЛ Вашего обработчика
        data: { xmlUrl: $(this).attr('data-link') } //сами данные, передается POST[xmlUrl] со значением из data-link нажатой кнопки
    })
    .done(function( res ) { //при успехе (200 статус)
       // а вот с этой частью уже не могу сообразить, как заставить изменить переменную
 $page.html(res) //заменяем блок с id="result" полученной строкой от сервера.
    });
});
</script>
```

обработчик:

```
<?php 
$page = $_POST['xmlUrl'];
?>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильно  реализовать

Answer (score 2):

script.js:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#smbBtn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"./query.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'val':$('#div_var').val()},
            success: function(res){
                r = JSON.parse(res);
                $('#div_var').val(r.value);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("request error");
            },
        });
    });
});
```

query.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["val"]))
{
    $this_var = $_POST["val"] + 1;
    echo json_encode(array('value' => $this_var));
}
?>
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="div_var" value="22" />
    <input type="button" id="smbBtn" />
</body>
</html>
```

100% рабочий пример ajax запроса, и изменение переменной в php

Comment: Не произошло никакой реакции, скрипт вставил ваш без изменений

Comment: Вы его не вставить должны были, а посмотреть чем он от вашего отличается, и принять меры.

Comment: Могли бы вы дать наводку что не так с вашим кодом? Возможно я слишком плохо знаю ajax, но буду стараться это исправить:)

Comment: @Алекс внес изменения в ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличное решение! Таким образом можно решить массу задач. Очень точно решает задачу "по нажатию на кнопку изменить значение переменной php"