# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: php, json

```
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'inc/engine.php',
            data: {
                type: 'updatebalance',
                sid: Cookies.get('sid')
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (obj.success == 'success') {
                    updateBalance(obj.balance, obj.new_balance);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 3000);
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'inc/engine.php',
            data: {
                type: 'updateout',
                sid: Cookies.get('sid')
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (obj.success == 'success') {
                    $('#withdrawT').html(obj.upd_bd);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Где вопрос? В чем проблема?

Comment: Виталий уже помог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //когда страница прогрузилась
   // ваш код
});
```

ну и подключить `jQuery` в `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

скрипт лучше вынести в другой файл

Comment: спасибо большое, я подключил jQuery и всё работает, но пришлось отключить "прелоад" перед загрузкой сайта, идёт подгрузка как бы, так вот я не понял куда именно вставлять код "когда страница прогрузилась"

Comment: @VadimSamoilov [в ответе на вопрос есть мой код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/864095/ajax-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-php/864098#864098) посмотрите как там организовано. Этот код значит что все функции внутри будут доступны после того, как все элементы страницы полность прогрузятся.

Comment: @VadimSamoilov Если вам помогли, то поставьте галочку, чтобы другие знали что вопрос решен и как благодарность автору, за уделенное вам время.